# Refer to a pillar value in pillar itself

Tags: salt-stack

I could not find a clear reference for that - is it possible to refer to one pillar value in another pillar value?

```
one: Hello
two: {{ one }} world  # This syntax is invalid
```

I tried `{{ one }}` and `{{ pillar['one'] }}` but both fail. Is it possible to achieve it at all in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly, but you can make a variable and reference it in multiple places:

```
{%- set value = "Hello" %}

one: {{ value }}
two: {{ value }} world
```

Not what you asked for, but maybe close to what you wanted, if what you were really looking for was a single point of truth.

This also works, and is useful for multiple vars:

```
{%- load_yaml as vars %}
var1: something
var2: else
{%- endload %}

one: {{ vars.var1 }}
two: {{ vars.var2 }}
three: {{ vars.var1 }}
# and so on
```

Both cases create a jinja variable that isn't pillar data in itself, but can be used to define pillar data.